# It is always necessary to include a Flatten layer after a set of 2D convolutional layers for convolutional neural networks in Keras?

Tags: neural-networks, conv-neural-network, keras, convolution

It is no clear for me when to use the flatten operation for building convnets.
It is always necessary to include a flatten operation after a set of 2D convolutions (and pooling)?

For example, let us suppose these two models for binary classification. They take as input a 2D numerical matrix of 2 rows and 15 columns and has as output a vector of two positions (positive and negative).

Model 1:

```
model = keras.models.Sequential([
        keras.Input(shape=(2,15,1)),
        keras.layers.Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(2, 1), activation="relu"),
        keras.layers.Flatten(),
        keras.layers.Dense(100, activation="relu"),
        keras.layers.Dropout(0.2),
        keras.layers.Dense(100, activation="relu"),
        keras.layers.Dropout(0.2),
        keras.layers.Dense(2, activation="softmax")
])
```

Model 2:

```
model = keras.models.Sequential([
        keras.Input(shape=(2,15,1)),
        keras.layers.Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(2, 1), activation="relu"),
        keras.layers.Dense(100, activation="relu"),
        keras.layers.Dropout(0.2),
        keras.layers.Dense(100, activation="relu"),
        keras.layers.Dropout(0.2),
        keras.layers.Dense(2, activation="softmax")
])
```

What is the difference between both? Do they have the same capacity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to see what's going in your models (not restricted to keras) is to print the model summary. In keras/tensorflow, you can do that via `model.summary()`. For the second (not flattened) one, it prints the following:

```
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
conv2d_3 (Conv2D)            (None, 1, 15, 32)         96        
_________________________________________________________________
dense_9 (Dense)              (None, 1, 15, 100)        3300      
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_6 (Dropout)          (None, 1, 15, 100)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_10 (Dense)             (None, 1, 15, 100)        10100     
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_7 (Dropout)          (None, 1, 15, 100)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_11 (Dense)             (None, 1, 15, 2)          202       
=================================================================
Total params: 13,698
Trainable params: 13,698
Non-trainable params: 0
```

So, the output has dimension 1 x 15 x 2, which is not the case for flattened version, i.e. 2. For the first one, it is:

```
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
conv2d_2 (Conv2D)            (None, 1, 15, 32)         96        
_________________________________________________________________
flatten_1 (Flatten)          (None, 480)               0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_6 (Dense)              (None, 100)               48100     
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_4 (Dropout)          (None, 100)               0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_7 (Dense)              (None, 100)               10100     
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_5 (Dropout)          (None, 100)               0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_8 (Dense)              (None, 2)                 202       
=================================================================
Total params: 58,498
Trainable params: 58,498
Non-trainable params: 0
```

Apparently, their capacities are different, e.g. number of parameters etc. The unflattened version carries the channel information till the end, e.g. the Dense layer is applied to all 15 channels with input size 32 (33 with bias). Since it has 100 neurons, it makes 3300 parameters. But, in the flattened version, the input vector has no channels and it has 480 (481 with bias) as its dimension, so it makes 48100 parameters at that stage.

Therefore, the two models are quite different.